# What is the term for large photo modals? Is there anything better than "lightbox"?

Tags: terminology

What is the best term for a UI showing **large image or image gallery in a modal**?

[image: screenshot of a big image on an e-commerce site]

Two common use cases are **e-commerce sites** and **photo galleries**.

The first term that comes to mind is **lightbox** as the [original JS library](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) was called like that and the terms seems to have caught on in the JS / web ecosystem, e.g., ["7 Best WordPress Lightbox Plugins"](https://themeisle.com/blog/wordpress-lightbox-plugins/) or ["How to create a lightbox"](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp).

One possible reservation is that "lightbox" generally means "a piece of UI that is above the page, with the rest of the page dimmed". Even if the modal is very small, it is still a "lightbox UI".

I quite liked the term **"theater"** mentioned [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/90337/48933) – that makes me think about something taking almost the full screen, which is good. However, I've never seen this term used in any UI library / toolkit I've ever used, unlike e.g. "hero" (which is also "strange" but once you get used to it, it is clear and unique).

Comment: What happened to 'lightbox'? What made you try to come with a new term for this?

Comment: What is exactly the reason you are looking for that name? Because that can have impact on the resulting answer. Call it a media viewer, preview, theater etc. to name it after the purpose it has, no matter in what way it is viewed. Or call it a lightbox, modal, popup etc. if it is important to communicate the specific UI component, no matter what purpose it has.

Comment: Lightbox as a term is older than js library with the same name (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox). And it too might be misunderstanding and should be called Light table (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_table).

Comment: Media Viewer is good. It tells the user what it does

Comment: I use Slideshow.

Answer (score 1):

Pop gallery, gallery up, popgall, imagomodal, gallmodal, imagoboom, gallboom, gallpopover, galleryfirst. Some ideas :)

Comment: seems a bit silly. But this is a strange time.