# Is it a good practice to use tooltip and a popover on the same UI element?

Tags: tooltips, popover

Previously I have only for desktop application. So I used tooltips to show some additional information on specific UI elements

Now I am going responsive with same application

So, since tooltips are not recommended on mobile as there is no hover on mobiles  - so I thought of changing the behaviour to popover from desktop to mobile all over and show it on a click, but did necessary changes on the UI elements so that it looks clickable.

However, the question from stakeholders is - why cant  we use both tooltip and popover - if user hover they can see tooltip and if user click they can see popover

So wanted to check is it good practice to have tooltip + popover on same UI element ?

Comment: Hi UX Beginner, how would an interaction with a tooltip and popover on the same element look like? First comes a tooltip and when you click it is overlayed by a popover?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with **popovers only** in your case. It works for mobile and desktop users.

Using both would be weird for the user because then nobody knows if you have to hover over something or click on it to get additional information.

As noted in [this answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/88844/when-should-i-use-a-popover-vs-a-tooltip) both tooltips and popovers have problems with accessibility, seo optimization and the bad discoverability. So be sure to only use them if you need them.